# Connectedness and Compactness of $\mathbb{N}$ with basic sets of the form $\mathbb{N}_{\ge n}$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

We have $X = \mathbb N$. The topology is generated by the basic sets $A_n = \{n,n+1,n+2,...\} , n\in \mathbb N$. Is $X$ connected and compact? My guess is that if we take any two open sets, one of them has to be contained in the other and hence, $X$ is both connected and compact.

Comment: Your conclusion is right.

Comment: Hint: If $S$ is any nonempty set of natural numbers and $N$ is the smallest element of $S$ then $\bigcup_{n\in S}A_n=A_N$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, correct !

Formally, the closed sets are of the form $\{1,2\dots,n\}$. So the only clopen sets are empty and whole set itself, so connected.

Compactness follows from the fact that $A_1=\Bbb N$ is a member of **every** open cover of $\Bbb N$ (as the only open set that contains $1$).

Comment: yes..edited.. Thanks